# Do lychees cause encephalitis?

Tags: brain, fruit, neurodegenerative-disorders

In India, there is a recent outbreak of this disease after many consumed lychees. 
Many people link this to lychee's "toxins".
I'm not a biology major hence can't elaborate further on this, but here are some links.

[Link 1](https://m.timesofindia.com/india/aes-outbreak-toxins-behind-litchi-deaths/amp_articleshow/69920018.cms)

[Link 2](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/langlo/article/PIIS2214-109X(17)30035-9/fulltext)

Here is another that claims that lychees must not be consumed empty stomach .

[Link 3](https://www.timesnownews.com/health/article/encephalitis-death-toll-crosses-100-in-bihar-why-you-should-not-eat-lychees-or-litchis-on-an-empty-stomach/438815)

Comment: There are many articles on this topic (including many intended for laypersons). Did you even try to read the articles carefully, that you yourself mentioned? I'm voting to put this question on hold because I don't even see a question here.

Comment: @WYSIWYG the studies are published by the newspapers, which in general shouldn't be considered reputable . I only asked here to verify if there is an actual scientific evidence for this.

Comment: Your second link is an article in *Lancet*, a highly reputed medical journal.